# Why the horizontal line behaves differently in supertabular and tabular?

Tags: tables, rules, supertabular

I have a problem using the supertabular package. Basically the horizontal lines, instead of stopping at the end of the table, continue until the end of the page.

This is a self-explaining screenshot. The first is a **supertabular**, the second is a **tabular**:

[image: screenshot]

And here's the code. I tried to cut it in order to make it as short as possible but still keeping it functioning. What am I doing wrong? I'm not very expert at LaTeX so I might be missing something.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{supertabular}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
%\newcolumntype{v}[1]{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tablehead {%
\hline
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \tabularnewline
}
\tabletail{%
}
\label{tab:lead_overview}

\begin{supertabular*}{\textwidth}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
    \hline
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{supertabular*}


\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
     \hline
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11  \\ \hline
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In your `supertabular` you have told it to be as wide as the `\textwidth`, so it's doing what you're telling it to!

Comment: @cmhughes I tried removing it, but if I do it gives me an error. What should I specify instead of that?

Comment: Use `\begin{supertabular}{|c|c...` instead of `\begin{supertabluar*}{\textwidth}...`

Comment: @cmhughes That worked! If you post that as an answer I can accept it. Thanks. :) Like I said, I am not that expert. When you post it, could you include what is that * meaning? Or some links would be good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `supertabular*` which is used in the same way as `tabular*`, i.e, it takes a width as its first argument.

You have specified the width of your `supertabular*` as `\textwidth`, so your `\hline` is drawn across the width of the page.

From your question, it sounds like you would prefer to use the `supertabular` environment, which does *not* take a width as its first argument. In the context of your example, it sounds like you want the following code:

```
\begin{supertabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
    \hline
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{supertabular}
```

For further reading, start with the documentation

```
texdoc supertabular
```

and you can also have a look at the `booktabs` documentation, which gives some excellent discussion/advice on constructing tables.